# Is there a validated tutorial for a claims-aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application using WIF for Visual Studio 2015 with .net 4.6?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, wif

I am looking to learn more about Windows Identity Framework, and would like to go through the tutorial posted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx) the problem is this is written for Visual Studio 2012. I am running Visual Studio 2015. I have looked around, and do not see updated procedures. What is the right thing to do here? There are many discrepancies between the procedures and what I see in Visual Studio 2015 such as the template names, and the options provided after a template is chosen.

@ Wiktor Zyckla - Thank you so much. This seems like what I was after.

Comment: Start with simple tutorial of mine http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html and come back with more detailed questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just be aware that WIF is deprecated (although still supported). The modern approach is to use OpenID Connect via OWIN.

e.g. [Integrate Azure AD into a web application using OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect).

If you want to use WIF, refer [Integrating a web app with Azure AD using WS-Federation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/) which shows WIF via OWIN.

I've got both of these working on VS 2015.

Comment: @nzpcmad-I am glad you mentioned this. I got to WIF, when I ran into Windows Identity while I was learning about threads and tasks. I kept digging, and learned about claims, and principles and did run into openID. You saved me a lot of time. I'll certainly review the links you shared.

Comment: What does it mean "deprecated"? Any actual reference to this or just an opinion based on the fact that OWIN has its own implementation?

Comment: No new development is being done on WIF. It's still supported but all the new features etc. are being added to the OWIN stack. The default stack in VS is now OpenID Connect not WIF. ADFS v.4.0 supports OIDC so again that's the way any new tools will be going. Nothing wrong with WIF - I still use it on occasion - but starting from scratch OWIN would be the way to go.

Comment: Per Vittorio "Modern Auth" pg. 82: "The WIF classes in the .NET Framework are still supported today, in the same way in which the
framework itself is supported, However, WIF is no longer the recipient of innovation, and all efforts and new features are concentrated on a new generation of libraries. Although WIF proved to be an excellent product—ferrying an entire generation to the claims-based identity era is no small feat—its extensibility model and configuration mechanisms were too rooted to its XML legacy. Proper modern protocols support required some backtracking and a fresh start."

Comment: WIF was never about OAuth/OIDC and I would be surprised to see it there, thus, I guess, if someone asks for WIF they mean WS-Fed. Redirecting them to OAuth and referring to WIF/WS-Fed as "deprecated" sounds almost like biased then. Nothing agaist OWIN/OAuth but I still wait till they support WS-Fed on .NET Core though: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/500

Comment: Follow up- Thanks. This last comment may be in line with what I was about to ask, which is: how does this impact a Thread's execution context? According to Jeff Richer's CLR via C#, the execution context is composed of security settings (compressed stack, Thread ’s Principal property, and Windows identity), host settings , and logical call
context data. So my question is what is going to happen to Windows Identity class? I am looking forward to reading OAuth/OIDC and OWIN.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but nothing is going to happen to WIF. It's part of the supported .NET framework and will remain there.

Comment: @Wiktor - I don't disagree with you. My point was that if you are new to this field, OWIN WS-Fed is a better way to go than WIF.

Comment: @nzpcmad: I don't disagree, too, just complain a bit about OWIN still being unpolished which makes the choice not that obvious imho.